# Подключиться к sqlite3 на C unable to open database file

Tags: java, android, c++, c, sqlite

Подключаю sqlite в нативе на андроид. 
Вылетает ошибка   `unable to open database file`

```
#include <android/log.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "DatabaseHelper.h"
#include "../sqlite/sqlite3.h"

const char* SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo(a,b,c); INSERT INTO FOO 
VALUES(1,2,3); INSERT INTO FOO SELECT * FROM FOO;";
const int ERROR_STATE = -1;
const int SUCCESSFULLY_STATE = 0;

int createDatabase(char *dbPath) {
char TAG[20] = "NATIVE_SQL";
sqlite3 *db = 0; // хэндл объекта соединение к БД
char *err = 0;

// открываем соединение и тут вылетает ошибка! 
if(sqlite3_open(dbPath, &db)) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, TAG, "Error opened database: 
%s\n",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, TAG, "path: %s\n",dbPath);
    return ERROR_STATE;
}
...someone code
```

Примечание:
Если

> if(sqlite3_open("", &db)) {..

. то бд создает временный файл бд который удаляет во время закрытия. См.Документацию. **Так работает! Никаких ошибок нет.**

Как мне создать файл и подключиться к нему на сях?

---

Еще вот так попробовал, эффект тот-же: 
Прим:Файл руками я не создаю, надеюсь, что если его нет, он создастся сам.

```
if(sqlite3_open_v2(dbPath, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL)) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, TAG, "Error opened database2. %s\n",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return ERROR_STATE;
}
```

**Permissions in Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: А какой диск D на андроиде?

Comment: `sqlite3_open_v2("myDb.db", &db,...` тоже не сработает. полный путь указывал, тк пытался без андроида, создать на диске, не получилось

Comment: дык, может прав открыть просто не хватает? попробуй обычным `open ()`'ом открыть (`O_CREAT` не забудь) и посмотри что в `errno` будет...

Comment: Обычный open() Имеешь ввиду: `sqlite3_open("myDb.sqlite3", &db)` ?
B уточни пж про `O_CREAT`. Мб ответом. @Fat-Zer

Comment: @RomanAymaletdinov, нет, обычный POSIX'овский сишный `open ()` файла...

Comment: Надо сначала вызовом [Context.getDatabasePath()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) получить путь к файлу БД, а потом уже передавать его в `sqlite3_open`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev мне помог, но решило мою проблему не  `Context.getDatabasePath()`,  а `final File file = this.getFileStreamPath("myDb.db");`